# SuspiciousFileOperation at /index/

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-oscar

django-oscar wasn't displaying pictures of products when the media_root was outside the project root, so changing the media_root to project_root/public/media throws this error.

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /index/ 
The joined path (.../barbaranew/media/media_root/images/products/malaysian1.png) is located outside of the base path component (.../barbaranew/barbaralee_site/public/media)
```

And also why were the images not showing when the media_root was outside, thought it was safer that way.
Thanks
I have tried to makemigrations and migrate, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suspicious File Operation..The joined path ... is located outside of the base path component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625173/suspicious-file-operation-the-joined-path-is-located-outside-of-the-base-pa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my urls.py and solved the media_root problem

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
                            'django.views.static.serve',
                            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the code below in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and

In projects urls.py add this code

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```